# using .append to build a complex menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

To build a menu block which should be switchable with hide/unhide of the menu items, I'm using .append html.
The code idea is this:

```
     navigat += '<h3 class="infoH3"> <a id="' + menuID +'"'
                     + ' href="javascript:slideMenu(\'' + menuSlider + '\');">'
                     +  menuName + '</a></h3>';

     navigat += '<div id="' + menuSlider + '" style="display:none">';
     navigat += '    <ul>';
     navigat += '       <li>aMenu1</li>'
     navigat += '       <li>aMenu2</li>'
     navigat += '       <li>aMenu3</li>'
     navigat += '    </ul>';
     navigat += '<!-- menuName Slider --></div>';
     $("#someElement").append (navigat);
```

This is doing well .. so far.

But the point is:: 
I use JS to read the required menu items (eg. 'aMenu1' together with title and/or link info)  from a file to build all that, eg. for 'aMenu1' a complex  is composed and $("#someElement").append(someString) is used to add that the 'someElement'.

At the moment I build those html elements line by line. Also OK .. as far as the resulting string has the opening and closing tag, eg. `"<li>aMenu2</li>"`.

As can be seen from above posted code there is a line `"<div id="' + menuSlider + '" style="display:none">"`.
Appending that -- AFAIS -- the .append is automatically (????)  adding "`</div>`" which closes the statement.
That breaks my idea of the whole concept! The menu part isn't included in the 'menuSlider '.

QQ: How to change it -- NOT to have that "`</div`" added to it??

Günter

Comment: It seems this is about JavaScript and jQuery. Tagged accordingly; please fix if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you saying it's automatically adding a closing </div> even when you don't have it in your code?

Comment: It's probably not the issue, but you are missing semicolons after the `li` items

Answer (score 0):

You could change you method around to use document fragment style creation and [an object to populate the properties on the elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), like this:

```
var someElement = $("#someElement");
$('<h3 class="infoH3"></h3>').append($('<a />', 
     { 'id': menuID,
       'href': '#',
       click: function() { slideMenu(menuSlider); }
     })
 ).appendTo(someElement);

var div = $('<div />', { 'id': menuSlider, css: {display: 'none'} });
$('<ul />').append('<li>aMenu1</li>')
           .append('<li>aMenu2</li>')
           .append('<li>aMenu3</li>')
           .appendTo(div);
div.appendTo(someElement);
```

This is a very different way of doing it, first we're caching the `$("#someElement")` object so we're not searching for it repeatedly.  Then we're creating the `<h3>` as an object, putting the link inside, then inserting then appending the whole thing to `someElement`.  In the last, the same approach it's creating the `<div>`, setting it's properties, then creates the `<ul>` menu and appends it inside...then appends that whole div to `someElement` as well.

As a side note, I'm not sure how `.slideMenu()` works, but an event handler that works via `$(this).parent().next()` (or give the div a class) would work as well, and you wouldn't need a function with the slider argument passed.